# Listening to characteristic value change from multiple connected BLE devices in iOS

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, swift5

I have a custom made BLE device with runs on BLE v4.1 and I am using swift 5 to make an iOS app which is able to connect to all the BLE devices in range of iOS phone.

I am able to connect and show all the devices (which have particular name) and I am showing them in a table. On the other hand, I have the complete implementation for connecting to the first discovered BLE device, discover services, discover characteristics, read value of characteristics using didUpdateValueFor delegate method in BTService.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    NSLog("didUpdateValue function called from BTService")

      if error != nil {
         print("ERROR ON UPDATING VALUE FOR CHARACTERISTIC: \(characteristic) - \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
         return
      }
    print("updating value of peripheral \(String(describing: peripheral))")
    print("Value of characteristic updated and didUpdateValueFor called. Value of characteristic is: \(characteristic.value!)")

      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
         self.didReceiveData(characteristic.uuid, characteristic.value!)

                if characteristic == OTAUpgradeCharacteristic {
                    NSLog("Value updated for bootloader characteristic")

                    bootloaderModel.peripheralValueUpdate(peripheral, characteristic: characteristic, error: error)

                }
      })
   }
```

I want to simultaneously read the value of characteristics being advertised in multiple connected BLE devices of same kind. All the BLE devices I'm connecting to have same advertisement name and same characteristics but different identifier. Each device may send different value of characteristic. Every time I try to read the advisement data from multiple connected BLE devices simultaneously, my code only reads the data from last connected device.

Is there any kind of library or code I can use to get the advertisement data from all the devices simultaneously or `didUpdateValueFor` being called for each of the connected peripheral?

Answer (score 0):

"get the advertisement data" could be interpreted a couple ways. Advertisement data is a type of information that is part of the BLE advertising process, that you receive as part of the CentralManager scan process and would not show up on the function shown above. I assume advertisement data is being used generically here to mean characteristic data that can be read or listened to after your app connects to a peripheral.

In short, each time your code connects to a device via CentralManager connect(_:options:), iOS creates a connection for that specific peripheral. So your code needs to hold a reference to the peripheral and you have to assign a delegate for each peripheral, do service/characteristic discovery for each, etc. The code may be doing so with a single class that is behaving as the delegate for each connected peripheral. The snippet above implies this, but it doesn't show for sure.

We would need to see the code that is being used to handle service and characteristic discovery as well as to sign up for notifications or to generate the read request to see for sure what is going on. I suspect that there is an issue there. Most likely the read request is only being made on a single characteristic. In addition to holding on to the peripheral, I believe you have to hold on to the CBCharacteristic for each device. If for example you are storing 
a single CBCharacteristic for all peripherals, that could cause this issue.

A bit more detail would be helpful, but likely the issue is around how the read is being done, and management of CBPeripheral and CBCharacteristic references.